# Rotating offset coordinates

Tags: java, math, graphics, coordinates

I have a section of map I can rotate, after rotating the coordinates I offset them so the top-left co-ordinate is (0,0). This works fine and I can add additional overlays to the map by performing the same rotation offset combination.

```
rotate(x) -> offset1
```

The problem is if I try and perform a second rotation i.e.

```
rotate(x) -> offset1 -> rotate(y) -> offset2
```

Is it possible to combine the two rotations and offsets into a single rotate offset combination and get the same result?

```
rotate(x+y) -> offset3
```

where offset3 = offset1 + offset2

This is so I can add overlays in the correct position regardless of how many rotation/offsets there have been. Id like to store a single value for the rotation and offset and not have a stack of previous operations.

Aside from removing the previous rotate/offset entirely before performing the new operations i.e. NOT

```
 -offset1 -> rotate(-x) - > rotate(y) -> offset2
```

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). Use this matrix to apply a translation of (tx,ty) for a 2D-vector (x,y):

[image: translation]

And this matrix for a rotation by theta:

[image]

Multiple translations and rotations can be combined by simply multiplying the matrices. (The order is important.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix translation perform offsets, rotations and scaling. You can combine these by multiplying the matrices together.